# Javascript element.click() or select value change should fire an event but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

So I'm using Enjoy Hint to make an auto guide for the website I'm working on. In order for the auto guide to exemplify things to the user, it should be able to do everything that a user does.

I have a select that triggers a function on option change using knockout's data-bind:

```
<select class="pattern-field-select field-large-select uppercase" tabindex="1" id="cm-alterarservico-listsituacoesos" data-bind="options: listSituacoesOrdemServico, optionsText: 'descricao', value: TlsosSituacao, optionsCaption: 'Selecione...', optionsValue: 'id'">
<option value="">Selecione...</option>
<option value="3">Aprovado</option>
<option value="7">Cancelado</option>
<option value="8">Interrompido</option></select>
```

This event makes new elements to appear somewhere else on the same page, so Enjoy Hint should be able to trigger this function, but the value changes only on the page and not on the function behind this. The function is not even being executed:

```
// Important variables, the rest is being omitted.
this.TlsosSituacao = ko.observable();
this.TlsosSituacaoFixa = ko.observable();

this.TlsosSituacao.subscribe(function (tlsossituacao) {
// Here, tlsossituacao is the option value, taken as argument.

// listSituacoesOrdemServico() is returning, on the above case, this: [
            //    {
            //        "id": 3,
            //        "descricao": "Aprovado",
            //        "valor": "aprovado"
            //    },
            //    {
            //        "id": 7,
            //        "descricao": "Cancelado",
            //        "valor": "cancelado"
            //    },
            //    {
            //        "id": 8,
            //        "descricao": "Interrompido",
            //        "valor": "interrompido"
            //    }
            //]

if (tlsossituacao != undefined ){
    if (tlsossituacao != instance.TlsosSituacaoFixa()) {
        instance.boolShowObservacaoOS(true);

        var valorselecionado = Enumerable.From(instance.listSituacoesOrdemServico()).Where(function (w) {
            return w.id == tlsossituacao
        }).Select(function (s) { return s.valor }).First();

        instance.listMotivosAlterarEstadoOSDisponiveis(Enumerable.From(instance.listAvailableMotivosAlterarEstadoOS()).Where(function (w) {
            return w.acao == valorselecionado
        }).ToArray());

    } else {
        instance.boolShowObservacaoOS(false);
        instance.TlsosObservacao("");
        instance.listMotivosAlterarEstadoOSDisponiveis(0);
    }
}
}, this);
```

Here's the step:

```
{
        selector: "table.table-resumo:nth-child(4) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1)",
        event: "next",
        event_type: "next",
        description: "Se o estado de um serviço é alterado, você deverá apontar um motivo.",
        "timeout": 500,
        "onBeforeStart": function () {
            document.getElementById("cm-alterarservico-listsituacoesos").selectedIndex = "3";
        }
    }
```

Things happen on the onBeforeStart function,which should do something before the step starts. I've tried several things:

- *document.getElementById("cm-alterarservico-listsituacoesos").selectedIndex
  = "2";* -> Changes the option value and text on the select box is changed, but then nothing happens.
- *document.getElementById("cm-alterarservico-listsituacoesos").value =
  "7";* -> Same as the above.
- *document.getElementById("cm-alterarservico-listsituacoesos").getElementsByTagName('option')[2].click();*
  -> Doesn't do anything.

Things work fine when the user clicks on the options, however, knockout is not responding to changes made directly through code. Any ideas on how to work this out?

Comment: Man, is there a reason why you are not using options binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html). Imo this seems like you over-complicating something that can be implemented much simpler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question . Am I not using options binding? Isn't it this: options: listSituacoesOrdemServico [...]? @Kadaj

Comment: Yeah, sorry didn't see right part, I was confused why do you have "<option value="">Selecione...</option>
<option value="3">Aprovado</option>
<option value="7">Cancelado</option>
<option value="8">Interrompido</option></select>", when you have options binding, it will create options list automatically for you.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. This is just an specifc example, but the options are actually being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working with knockout, you should be careful modifying the DOM in other ways than via a view model and a data-bind.

When you set the `selectedIndex` attribute, you're not letting knockout know something's changed. This means the viewmodel value won't update; it's like a one-way binding.

You have to change the actual value and let knockout update the UI.

This example should explain the difference between the two approaches a bit better:

- The left button will only change the element, and not update any viewmodel values. It's only changing the representation. You'll see **an updated UI, but no change notification in the console**.
- The right button finds the associated observable and changes that. Knockout updates the select box automatically. You'll see **both a notification in the console, and an updated UI**.

```js
var items = [1,2,3,4];
var selected = ko.observable();
selected.subscribe(console.log.bind(console));

ko.applyBindings({items: items, selected: selected });

document
  .querySelector(".js-btn1")
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    document.querySelector("select").selectedIndex = 1;
  });

document
  .querySelector(".js-btn2")
  .addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    ko.dataFor(document.querySelector("select")).selected(1);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, value: selected, optionsCaption: 'select a number'"></select>


<button class="js-btn1">Does not work</button>
<button class="js-btn2">Does work</button>
```

Comment: Worked. I knew that knockout wasn't updating the value, but I didn't know why. Thanks for explaining!